# How can I show/hide menu items in Nav Drawer and enable/disable overflow menu items in App Bar programatically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to do what the title says but have found no information on the web at all. In regular Android code, this is as simple as finding the ViewID of the drawer/toolbar, getting the menu item, and either calling .setEnabled() or .setVisible() on the menu item. How can I do this in Flutter? Basically when a certain url is loaded in webView, I want to either enable/disable or show/hide programatically (in the onLoadStart and onLoadFinished methods for webview_flutter). For reference, my scaffold:

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(appBarTitle),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.refresh,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          webView.reload();
        },
      ),
      PopupMenuButton<Choice>  ( //showchoice??
        onSelected: _select,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return choices.map((Choice choice) {
            return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
              value: choice,
              child: Text(choice.title),
            );
          }).toList();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),

  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new DrawerHeader(
          child: Column (
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget> [
            Text(
              'HLS Grades',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Canvas Online Grading System',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
        ]),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
        Divider(),
        Text(
          'Course Actions',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.assignment),
          title: Text('Assignments'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 0);
            _onSelectNavItem(0);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.grades),
          title: Text('Grades'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 1);
            _onSelectNavItem(1);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.people),
          title: Text('Users'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 2);
            _onSelectNavItem(2);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.syllabus),
          title: Text('Syllabus'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 3);
            _onSelectNavItem(3);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.discussions),
          title: Text('Discussions'),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 4);
            _onSelectNavItem(4);
          },
        ),
        Divider(),
        Text(
          'App Actions',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.logout),
          title: Text('Logout'),
          onTap: () {
            _onSelectNavItem(5);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(MyFlutterApp.settings),
          title: Text('Settings'),
          onTap: () {
            _onSelectNavItem(6);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

And the code for my choice class:

```
 class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'All Grading Periods'),
  const Choice(title: 'Trimester 1'),
  const Choice(title: 'Trimester 2'),
  const Choice(title: 'Trimester 3'),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whoever is stumped by this and is looking for an answer, just wrap your ListTile in a

```
Visibility (
    visible: _visible
    child: ListTile(...)
);
```

and whenever you want to remove, just

```
setState(() {
    _visible = false;
});
```

or whenever you want to show

```
setState(() {
    _visible = true;
});
```